# How to make multiple divs to scroll horizontally?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I want my tiles to be in the same row, and the container to scroll horizontally, if the tiles go beyond the width of the container.  Looking at the following demo, the tiles get added to the next row, so I have to scroll vertically to access them.  How can I make horizontal scroll work, and keep all tiles in the same row?

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  max-height: 140px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.tile {
  width: 200px;
  height: 92px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 10px 50px 10px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div><img class="tile"></div>
  <div><img class="tile"></div>
  <div><img class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're floating the wrong elements to the left. The `.tile` classes are all wrapped in other divs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `overflow-x:scroll;` and `overflow-y: hidden;` on parent, and `white-space:nowrap;`  on inner div and also `display: inline-block;` on `floatLeft`

```css
.container {
  width: 480px; 
  height: 140px; 
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  white-space:nowrap; 
}

.floatLeft {
  width: 200px;
  height: 92px; 
  margin:10px 10px 50px 10px; 
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="inner">
       <div class="floatLeft">
           <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="tile">
       </div>
       <div class="floatLeft">
           <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="tile">
       </div>
       <div class="floatLeft">
           <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="tile">
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice!  Thanks.  What is the reason for the inner div.  I can see that it works, but just wondering, why is it necessary?

Comment: For `white-space: no-wrap` but you can also do this without inner div https://jsfiddle.net/a66k3otb/1/

Answer (score 1):

Add display: inline-block to your containing divs css:

```
.floatleft{
 display: inline-block;
}
```

or alternatively you can add it as a style attribute on each div:

```
<body>
<div  class="container">
<div style="display: inline-block" class="floatLeft">
    <img class="tile">
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block" class="floatLeft">
    <img class="tile">
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block" class="floatLeft">
    <img class="tile">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Heres the working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/edencorbin/rq0L7x7v/

Comment: I would make a CSS change instead of adding the style in line: `.container > .floatLeft { display: inline-block; }`

Answer (score 0):

> I want my tiles to be in the same row, and the container to scroll horizontally, if the tiles go beyond the width of the container.

Your `.container` class has a fixed with of `480px`. If this is intentional then all you need to do is add `display: inline-block` to your `.floatLeft` class like so:

```
.container > .float-left {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Otherwise, you can make your `.container` class have a flexible width. If you like the suggestion, you can change the width to `min-width: 480px` that way your width will expand with your content.

```
.container {
  min-width: 480px; /* changes occurred here */
  max-height: 140px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

However, if your screen width is too small to hold many tiles, then they will align vertically in a new row, which is normal expected behavior. Or better yet, you could do both. The choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div  class="container" id="content">
    <div >
        <img src="img" height="190">
       <img src="img" height="190">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

    #content{
        width: auto;
        height:210px;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    #contentimg {
        border: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```