# HTML / CSS How do I force images to horizontally display

Tags: html, css, image

I have some code below that displays 6 images.  I want to display all 3 images under imagegroup0 horizontally next to each other and then all images of imagegroup1 horizontally as well, but under the images of imagegroup0.  The code posted below works unless the image is large enough so that not all 3 images are visible without scrolling.  When the images get too large, my browser displays them vertically.  My questions are:

1.How do I force the images of an image group to display horizontally even if it requires horizontal scrolling?
2.Is there a way to do that without having to declare the image groups to display explicitly?  Basically, I want to say, under a  place horizontally. (All images will be same size so alignment does not matter).

```css
#imagegroup0 div {
  display: inline-block;
}

#imagegroup1 div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="imagegroup0">
  <div id="image0.0">
    <figure>
      <img src="example.jpg" />
      <figcaption>image</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div id="image0.1">
    <figure>
      <img src="example.jpg" />
      <figcaption>image2</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div id="image0.2">
    <figure>
      <img src="example.jpg" />
      <figcaption>image3</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="imagegroup1">
  <div id="image1.0">
    <figure>
      <img src="example.jpg" />
      <figcaption>image</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div id="image1.1">
    <figure>
      <img src="example.jpg" />
      <figcaption>image2</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div id="image1.2">
    <figure>
      <img src="example.jpg" />
      <figcaption>image3</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update:** Here's what I ended up doing based on feedback below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>images</title>
    <style>
.group {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.group div {
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="group">
        <div>
            <figure>
                <img src="example.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>image</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure>
                <img src="example.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>image2</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure>
                <img src="example.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>image3</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <div>
            <figure>
                <img src="example.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>image</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure>
                <img src="example.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>image2</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div>
            <figure>
                <img src="example.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>image3</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can specify width for each image like you can give width: 30%; for each image.

Comment: you want solution with plain HTML and CSS, or u want solution with bootstrap framework

Comment: @Venkatachalam OP is not using BS, at least does not mention it and is not using it's structure

Comment: Here is detailed answer on your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796770/how-to-make-multiple-divs-to-scroll-horizontally
Also, I create a JSFiddle for your example: https://jsfiddle.net/c7Ln4tya/
Main problem is in missin white-space: nowrap; inner div

Comment: The answers below have covered your question I guess. Everyone of them is going to give you the solution you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `white-space: nowrap` and use classes to avoid writing out every class.

`nowrap` means all elements will stay on same line even if there is no more space for them and they would normally break on closest still in-box white-space

```css
.group {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.group div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="group" id="imagegroup0">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
<div class="group" id="imagegroup1">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#imagegroup0, #imagegroup1{
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="imagegroup0">
        <div id="image0.0">
            <figure>
                <img src="example.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>image</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div id="image0.1">
            <figure>
                <img src="example.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>image2</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div id="image0.2">
            <figure>
                <img src="example.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>image3</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="imagegroup1">
        <div id="image1.0">
            <figure>
                <img src="example.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>image</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div id="image1.1">
            <figure>
                <img src="example.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>image2</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div id="image1.2">
            <figure>
                <img src="example.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>image3</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give `width: 30%;` for each div.

```css
#imagegroup0 div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}

#imagegroup1 div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div id="imagegroup0">
  <div id="image0.0">
    <figure>
      <img src="example.jpg" />
      <figcaption>image</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div id="image0.1">
    <figure>
      <img src="example.jpg" />
      <figcaption>image2</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div id="image0.2">
    <figure>
      <img src="example.jpg" />
      <figcaption>image3</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="imagegroup1">
  <div id="image1.0">
    <figure>
      <img src="example.jpg" />
      <figcaption>image</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div id="image1.1">
    <figure>
      <img src="example.jpg" />
      <figcaption>image2</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div id="image1.2">
    <figure>
      <img src="example.jpg" />
      <figcaption>image3</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why `30%` and not `33.333333%` or `5%`?

Comment: Yes it can be 33.333%. I thought you can give to margin for the space in between.

Comment: That way will not be responsive, because `(30% + 2px) * 3` may add up to `>100%`. For spacing use `box-sizing: border-box; padding: ##px`

Comment: If margin is given in percentage, it will be responsive.

Comment: Usually you don't want gaps in percentage.

Answer (score 0):

One of the Posible solution is to use "Bootstrap framework"

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>images</title>
    <style>
#imagegroup0 div
{
display:inline-block;
}
#imagegroup1 div
{
display:inline-block;
}
img
{
 width:133px;
 height:133px;
}

</style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="imagegroup0">
        <div id="image0.0">
            <figure>
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/16/20/04/eye-491625_960_720.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>image</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div id="image0.1">
            <figure>
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/16/20/04/eye-491625_960_720.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>image2</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div id="image0.2">
            <figure>
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/16/20/04/eye-491625_960_720.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>image3</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="imagegroup1">
        <div id="image1.0">
            <figure>
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/16/20/04/eye-491625_960_720.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>image</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div id="image1.1">
            <figure>
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/16/20/04/eye-491625_960_720.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>image2</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div id="image1.2">
            <figure>
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/16/20/04/eye-491625_960_720.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>image3</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answers to your questions:
1.How do I force the images of an image group to display horizontally even if it requires horizontal scrolling? 
- You can use bootstrap and use class "table" which is fully responsive and it automatically displays images horizontally manner.

2.Is there a way to do that without having to declare the image groups to display explicitly? 
- Yes, as i said in answer of Q-1 you can use bootstrap "table"

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>images</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> 
    <style>
#imagegroup0 div
{
display:inline-block;
}
#imagegroup1 div
{
display:inline-block;
}
img
{
 width:333px;
 height:333px;
}

</style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
 <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="image0.0">
            <figure>
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/16/20/04/eye-491625_960_720.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>image1</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div id="image0.1">
            <figure>
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/16/20/04/eye-491625_960_720.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>image2</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div id="image0.2">
            <figure>
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/16/20/04/eye-491625_960_720.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>image3</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="image0.0">
            <figure>
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/16/20/04/eye-491625_960_720.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>image1</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div id="image0.1">
            <figure>
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/16/20/04/eye-491625_960_720.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>image2</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div id="image0.2">
            <figure>
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/16/20/04/eye-491625_960_720.jpg"/>
                <figcaption>image3</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Answers to your questions:

1.How do I force the images of an image group to display horizontally even if it requires horizontal scrolling?

- You can use bootstrap and use class "table" and "table-responsive" which is fully responsive and it automatically displays images horizontally manner and gives you a scroll whenever require.

2.Is there a way to do that without having to declare the image groups to display explicitly?

- Yes, as I said in answer to Q-1 you can use bootstrap "table"

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm very new to HTML and will lookup bootstrap table the next time I do something like this.