# HTML / CSS Layout - display 2 images vertically in 1 figure

Tags: html, css, layout

This is a follow-up question from this post:

[HTML / CSS How do I force images to horizontally display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43731537/html-css-how-do-i-force-images-to-horizontally-display)

The code below will display 6 figures.  Each figure contains a single image with a caption.  The figures are laid out 3 horizontally in 2 vertical groups.  Now I want to add an additional image to each of my figures directly below (vertical) the first image.  Rest of the layout should remain the same.  How do I do that? (I added the extra example image in each figure, but it displays horizontally instead of vertically.)

```css
  .group {
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    
    .group div {
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
 
        <div class="group">
            <div>
                <figure>
                    <img src="example.jpg"/>
                    <img src="example2.jpg"/>
                    <figcaption>image</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div>
                <figure>
                    <img src="example.jpg"/>
                    <img src="example2.jpg"/>
                    <figcaption>image2</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div>
                <figure>
                    <img src="example.jpg"/>
                    <img src="example2.jpg"/>
                    <figcaption>image3</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
            <div>
                <figure>
                    <img src="example.jpg"/>
                    <img src="example2.jpg"/>
                    <figcaption>image</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div>
                <figure>
                    <img src="example.jpg"/>
                    <img src="example2.jpg"/>
                    <figcaption>image2</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div>
                <figure>
                    <img src="example.jpg"/>
                    <img src="example2.jpg"/>
                    <figcaption>image3</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/ftfpmt1f/

Comment: use  .group div img{display:block;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put a `<br>` between the two images, i.e.

```
               <img src="example.jpg"/><br>
               <img src="example2.jpg"/>
               <figcaption>image</figcaption>
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!